# Replace old mobile app in play store / app store

Tags: mobile

I want to replace my old app in the app store &  play store. Since I want to combine the internationalization within one app this means that currently in every country there is a seperate version (app id) of the app. In future it should be one app (app id) which is enabled for all countries.

My question: how can I replace the old app with a new one (with a new app Id)  without losing:
- the number of users
- the number of downloads + ratings...

Is there some way to redirect within play store / app store from a deprecated app to a new one?

Thanks, 
Fahim

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Hi,  no more about the configuration. I don't see any possibility to publish my new app in the best way...

Comment: Why can't you just use the same app id and post an update?

Comment: Because I have several apps for different countries and I want to move to a single app which supports all countries.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that. It's not possible the way you have described. Your best option is to probably pick the existing localisation with the best download number/reviews and update that app id.